# How do I create a link to my React app from a Django template

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I am in the process of converting some Django apps to React but am having issues with something I thought was simple. I need to link directly to my react blog post app. Back when my blog app was a Django app I would link it like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'posts:details' 'title_of_blog_post' %}" class="alert-link"> Click here</a>
```

Now that my app is a react app, I need to link to the specific blog post without using the full external link. The only way I've been able to link to the app is to use `href="{% url 'posts-list' %}"`, but this just takes me to the landing page of the post app and not the specific post I need to render.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/posts/create' component={PostCreate}/>
            <Route exact path='/posts/' component={Posts}/>
            <Route exact path='/posts/:slug' component={PostDetail}/>
            <Route component={Posts}/>
          </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

posts.urls.py

```
    path('', views.PostListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='list-create'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.PostDetailAPIView.as_view(),
            name='detail'),
```

MySite.urls.py

```
    re_path(r'^posts/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='posts/react.html'),
            name='posts-list'),
    path('walking', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='posts/walking.html')),
    path('api/posts/', include('posts.urls')),
```

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

This seems to work, although my IDE throws an error:

```
<a href="/posts/title_of_blog_post" class="alert-link"> Click here</a>
```

Comment: The JSX syntax doesn't run in browsers ([actually it can, but it will affect the performance and only suitable for development](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx)). So, you'll have to compile that to JS which browsers can understand. You're better off running React and Django separately and transfer data between the two using an API.

Comment: Thanks! That's my ultimate end goal (to have react run the entirety of my frontend). I'm converting the site in pieces and need to have old apps (in django) link to the new react apps in the interim. Do you have any guidance on how I would go about compiling JSX to JS? I'm new to React and javascript, so apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: This page contains all the info you need: [Adding React to a Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx).